# I have a plunker. When I define my css globally, it works. When I define my css in my component, it fails. What's going on?

Tags: css, angular, material-design

With reference to this plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/GWsbdDWVvBYNMqyxzlLY?p=preview

I have the same css specified in the styles.css file, and in the src/app.ts file.

If I comment in the css in styles.css and comment out the css in src/app.ts, it works.

styles.css:

```
/* If these are commented in, and the ones in src/app.ts are 
 * commented out, the three items are spaced appropriately. */
/***
md-toolbar-row {
    justify-content: space-between;
}

md-toolbar {
    justify-content: space-between;
}
***/
```

If I comment out the css in styles.css and comment in the css in src/app.ts, it fails.

src/app.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <md-toolbar color="primary">
        <span><md-icon>mood</md-icon></span>

        <span>Yay, Material in Angular 2!</span>

        <button md-icon-button>
          <md-icon>more_vert</md-icon>
        </button>
      </md-toolbar>
    </div>
  `,
  // If these are commented in, and the ones in style.css are 
  // commented out, the three items are scrunched together.
  /***/
  styles: [
    `md-toolbar-row {
        justify-content: space-between;
    }`, 
    `md-toolbar {
        justify-content: space-between;
    }`
  ]
  /***/
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
}
```

I'm having trouble visualizing the difference between defining the css for the whole application, and for the specific component.  Can someone tell me what's going on?

=================================

@bryan60 and @Steveland83 seem to indicate that the problem lies somewhere in the view encapsulation.  And upon further investigation, it does in a sense.

If you look at the code below, you will see that the styles for md-toolbar and md-toolbar-row have an attribute attached.  But the html for md-toolbar and md-toolbar-row does not match.  Only md-toolbar has the attribute attached.  md-toolbar-row doesn't.  I have marked the relevant four lines with >>>>>.

So that's the problem but:
1.  Do I report it to the material design people as an error?
2.  Is there some workaround I can use today?

```
<html>
<head>
        : 
  <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('app')
            .catch(console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
    <link href="https://rawgit.com/angular/material2-builds/master/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
>>>>>   md-toolbar-row[_ngcontent-c0] {
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
    </style>
    <style>
>>>>>   md-toolbar[_ngcontent-c0] {
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
    </style>
    <style>
        .mat-toolbar {
            display: flex;
                :       : 
          .mat-mini-fab,
            .mat-raised-button {
                outline: solid 1px
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="mat-app-background">
    <my-app _nghost-c0="" ng-version="4.4.0-RC.0">
        <div _ngcontent-c0="">
            <h2 _ngcontent-c0="">Hello Angular! v4.4.0-RC.0</h2>
>>>>>       <md-toolbar _ngcontent-c0="" class="mat-toolbar mat-primary" color="primary" role="toolbar" ng-reflect-color="primary">
                <div class="mat-toolbar-layout">
>>>>>               <md-toolbar-row class="mat-toolbar-row">
                        <span _ngcontent-c0=""><md-icon _ngcontent-c0="" class="mat-icon material-icons" role="img" aria-hidden="true">mood</md-icon></span>

                        <span _ngcontent-c0="">Yay, Material in Angular 2!</span>

                        <button _ngcontent-c0="" class="mat-icon-button" md-icon-button=""><span class="mat-button-wrapper">
          <md-icon _ngcontent-c0="" class="mat-icon material-icons" role="img" aria-hidden="true">more_vert</md-icon>
        </span>
                            <div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple mat-button-ripple-round" md-ripple="" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLButtonElement]" ng-reflect-centered="true" ng-reflect-disabled="false"></div>
                            <div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div>
                        </button>
                    </md-toolbar-row>
                </div>
            </md-toolbar>
        </div>
    </my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: angular's css encapsulation is a little weird.  If defined at the component level, it only affects that component.  You can make it also apply to child components with special selectors, but this is pretty frustrating.  I'd prefer it if Angular offered an encapsulation mode that made styles defined cascade as CSS should.

Comment: @bryan60 The point of having styles in JS is precisely so you can scope them. If you want cascading styles, use CSS...

Comment: I know that is the purpose, but since it is CSS, it would make more sense if the scope in this case could be defined as the component and it's children.  This is the expectation of CSS scope in general and it's weird to break that convention or not even provide an option for it. The benefit to being able to scope it to the component and it's children should be obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, with help from @Steveland83 and @bryon60, I came to a definite answer.  The Material Design people are aware of this problem.  They have made a writeup.

https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/customizing-component-styles.md

Here's their summary:

#### Styling other components

If your component has view encapsulation turned on (default), your component styles will only
affect the top level children in your template. HTML elements belonging to child components cannot
be targeted by your component styles unless you do one of the following:

- Add the overriding style to you global stylesheet. Scope the selectors so that it only affects
  the specific elements you need it to.
- Turn view encapsulation off on your component. If you do this, be sure to scope your styles
  appropriately, or else you may end up incidentally targeting other components elswhere in your
  application.
- Use a deprecated shadow-piercing descendant combinator to force styles to apply to all the child
  elements. Read more about this deprecated solution in the
  [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep).

I don't want to use global css, or a deprecated solution.  I guess I will style with classes, and not elements.  If someone has a better idea, tell me!

Comment: Classes will give you greater specificity, so thats a cleaner approach I would certainly agree with - but since you will still need to add those styles to a component with ViewEncapsulation set to `None` or import them globally (e.g. in your angular-cli.json) I'd suggest that element vs class is a separate, loosely related question in its own right.

Comment: @Steveland83  Hmm.  You're right, Steve.  It doesn't solve the problem.  It forces me back to old-style global css.  
  
I found this:  
  
https://blog.angular.io/the-state-of-css-in-angular-4a52d4bd2700  
  
The summary is that the Angular folks promise to keep ::ng-deep around until browsers mature to the point that there is a truly good solution.

Answer (score 0):

One of the Angular features is `View Encapsulation` which basically means that you can define styles scoped only to a specific component without affecting any other components.

By default styles are scoped only for the component they are referenced in, but you can choose to override that to make them available globally by setting your components encapsulation to `None`.

E.g.

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'component-that-shares-styles',
  templateUrl: './component-that-shares-styles.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-that-shares-styles.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None // <-- Set encapsulation here
})
```

*Note that you will need to import `ViewEncapsulation` from `@angular/core`

Comment: I learned a little more.  One of the html lines has the _ngcontent-c0 attribute as it should, but one does not.

Comment: Yes, this is to facilitate the scoping. Here's a nice article you may find useful: https://coryrylan.com/blog/css-encapsulation-with-angular-components